# Handling Requests in Blazor Auto Render Mode

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

In Blazor Auto Render mode, you face a unique challenge because your app operates in two distinct environments: server-side rendering (SSR) and client-side rendering (CSR). Now, consider a scenario where you have an API app (with token-based authorization) and a client app built using Blazor with Auto Render mode. How can you effectively access the API app from the client app?

I Try Following Step

1. **Add HttpClient Instances**:

   - In your Blazor app, add an instance of HttpClient. Add A Instance for server-side rendering (SSR) and another for client-side rendering (CSR).
   - Configure the base address and other settings for each HttpClient instance.
2. **Create an Interface (IHttpClientFactory)**:

   - Define an interface named **`IHttpClientFactory`** that abstracts the creation of HttpClient instances.
   - This interface will allow you to switch between server and client implementations seamlessly.
3. **Implement the Interface for Server and Client**:

   - Create two classes that implement the **`IHttpClientFactory`** interface: one for the server and one for the client.
   - In the server implementation, use the server-side HttpClient.
   - In the client implementation, use the client-side HttpClient (scoped to the component).
4. **Inject the Interface**:

   - In your Blazor components or pages, inject the **`IHttpClientFactory`** interface.
   - Based on the execution environment (server or client), you’ll get the appropriate implementation.
5. Within the service that uses the **`IHttpClientFactory`**, create logic to adapt to the environment:

   - For SSR, use the server-side HttpClient directly.
   - For CSR, use the client-side HttpClient.

   But I believe we require a clearer approach to handle requests in Blazor’s Auto Render Mode.

   We also face additional challenges, such as retrieving user claims, verifying authentication in the client app, and adding a bearer token to HTTP client requests

   **I appreciate if you sharing your insights on this issue.**

Comment: Does this article help you? https://auth0.com/blog/auth0-authentication-blazor-web-apps/

Comment: Yes, Auto render mode is challengingI  I call them contexts, and there are three not two - you forgot the `HttpRequest` context in Pre-Render.   See this commentary I put together - https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazor.ExploreRendering/blob/master/Documents/Going-For-Broke.md    Does your API live in the SSR application?

Comment: @TeodorVladutu I don't want to depend on a paid service

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis It was a good article, but it explained more about the difference between different modes and how we can understand which mode we are using now, but it didn't say anything special about my question about how to access the resources.

Comment: Does your API live in the SSR application or are they separate?  In other words do you need the HttpClient in pre-render and SSR mode?

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis `consider a scenario where you have an API app (with token-based authorization)` A seprated webapi app

Comment: I have, and the complexity of a medium/large app, such as the one I'm currently working on, was a bit scary.  I had planned on using Auto, but when I started to work out the complexity I quickly decided the cost wasn't worth it.  I stayed with Server.  Working on a Demo project to test it properly with say Azure authentication is still in my To Do list.

Comment: @AMB The article explained how the issue you were facing was solved. You can make abstraction of the auth0 library/service. The base idea was to synchronize the app state between the SSR and CSR client.